# Bash / Substring of a string

Tags: linux, bash

I try to find a substring of a string.

If I have the string `try-30/16`, I want to get the `30` string.

so I wrote the next:

```
n=${"'$b'":'-':'/'}
```

where $b is a variable I assign before this command. It gives the next:

bad substitution.

How I can do it?

Comment: What about awk? $ `echo "try-30/16" | awk -F"[-/]" '{print $2}'`

Comment: note that the parameter expansion you are using have this syntax `${parameter:offset:length}`. It extracts substring based on index. The [parameter expansion part of Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
b="try-30/16"
n=${b##*-}
n=${n%%/*}
echo $n
```

Comment: +1. This is a good answer, but could still be improved by pointing to [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) documentation.

Comment: Though it wouldn't matter for OP's question, but `##` and `%%` removes the longest match. We can do with just `#` and `%` in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ n=${b%/*}
$ n=${n#*-}
$ echo $n
30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
[[ $b =~ [^-]+-([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
30
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/bKHGcS